# Slideshows(Multiple) for HTML/Webpage

Tags: javascript, css, slideshow, html

I am attempting to put two slideshows on the same page, both of which would be ran by the same css, and java script. My issue is that I can not seem to figure out why my second slideshow is pushing one of the images down. Notice in the photo provided that the second slideshow is pushing the image of a white circle vertically down and to the left of the page. If anyone can explain what I have done wrong, I would appreciate it and any other advice as well!  Thank you

[image]

```
The Image of the result of my slideshows( two of them)
```

```js
<script>
   

     //1. set ul width
        //2. image when click prev/next button
        var ul;
        var li_items;
        var imageNumber;
    var imageWidth;
    var prev, next;
    var currentPostion = 0;
    var currentImage = 0;


    function init(){
     ul = document.getElementById('image_slider');
     li_items = ul.children;
     imageNumber = li_items.length;
     imageWidth = li_items[0].children[0].clientWidth;
     ul.style.width = parseInt(imageWidth * imageNumber) + 'px';
     prev = document.getElementById("prev");
     next = document.getElementById("next");
     //.onclike = slide(-1) will be fired when onload;
     /*
     prev.onclick = function(){slide(-1);};
     next.onclick = function(){slide(1);};*/
     prev.onclick = function(){ onClickPrev();};
     next.onclick = function(){ onClickNext();};
    }

    function animate(opts){
     var start = new Date;
     var id = setInterval(function(){
      var timePassed = new Date - start;
      var progress = timePassed / opts.duration;
      if (progress > 1){
       progress = 1;
      }
      var delta = opts.delta(progress);
      opts.step(delta);
      if (progress == 1){
       clearInterval(id);
       opts.callback();
      }
     }, opts.delay || 17);
     //return id;
    }

    function slideTo(imageToGo){
     var direction;
     var numOfImageToGo = Math.abs(imageToGo - currentImage);
     // slide toward left

     direction = currentImage > imageToGo ? 1 : -1;
     currentPostion = -1 * currentImage * imageWidth;
     var opts = {
      duration:1000,
      delta:function(p){return p;},
      step:function(delta){
       ul.style.left = parseInt(currentPostion + direction * delta * imageWidth * numOfImageToGo) + 'px';
      },
      callback:function(){currentImage = imageToGo;}
     };
     animate(opts);
    }

    function onClickPrev(){
     if (currentImage == 0){
      slideTo(imageNumber - 1);
     }
     else{
      slideTo(currentImage - 1);
     }
    }

    function onClickNext(){
     if (currentImage == imageNumber - 1){
      slideTo(0);
     }
     else{
      slideTo(currentImage + 1);
     }
    }

    window.onload = init;
    </script>
```

```css
    /* Silent Auction */
/* SLIDESHOW */

  .container2{
     width:800px;
     height:400px;
     padding:5px;
     border:1px solid #E6E6FA;
     -webkit-box-sizing:border-box;
     -moz-box-sizing:border-box;
     box-sizing:border-box;
     background: #E6E6FA;
    }
.slider_wrapper{
 overflow: hidden;
 position:relative;
 height:500px;
 top:auto;
}
#image_slider{

 position: relative;
 height: auto;
 list-style: none;
 overflow: hidden;
 float: left;
 /*Chrom default padding for ul is 40px */
 padding:0px;
 margin:0px;
}
#image_slider li{
 position: relative;
 float: left;
}
.nvgt{
 position:absolute;
 top: 120px;
 height: 50px;
 width: 30px;
 opacity: 0.6;
}
.nvgt:hover{
 opacity: 0.9;
}
#prev{
 background: #000 url('https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/65639888/image/prev.png') no-repeat center;
 left: 0px;
}
#next{
 background: #000 url('https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/65639888/image/next.png') no-repeat center;
 right: 0px;
}
h1.slideshowtitle{
  font-style: italic;
  font-size: 50px;
  font-family: cursive;
  color: black;
```

```html
    <h1> Silent Auction </h1>


    <!-First Slideshow->
    <div class="container2">
      <div class="slider_wrapper">
        <ul id="image_slider">
          <li><img src=""></li>
          <li><img src=""></li>
          <li><img src=""></li>
        </ul>
        <span class="nvgt" id="prev"></span>
        <span class="nvgt" id="next"></span>
      </div>
    </div>
    <!-Second slide show ->
    <div class="container2">
      <div class="slider_wrapper">
        <ul id="image_slider">
          <li><img src=""></li>
          <li><img src=""></li>
          <li><img src=""></li>
        </ul>
        <span class="nvgt" id="prev"></span>
        <span class="nvgt" id="next"></span>
      </div>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ids should be unique within the document, but you are styling w/ id selectors and multiple elements with the same id. Switch to classes. E.g. -

Use

```
class="image_slider"
```

and

```
.image_slider { <yourcss> }
```

Comment: I will try this right now and let you know if it fixes this, thank you!

Comment: Ok so I changed just the image_slider id to a class  and changed my javascript accordingly and it did not fix it(it made both slideshows drop the second image just like the photo above), if I go through and change all of the id's to classes do you think this will fix it? @wilcosprey

Comment: No that won't fix it. But at least your style is being applied consistently across both slideshows. Now you just need to get the CSS right and everything else should fall in to place.

Comment: Are you setting the width and size on both image_slider elements? Did you rename them to have two distinct ids or query them by classname or something else?

Comment: I will post the new code when I get a chance, sorry at work at the moment.  But as for the image_slider id's, I have not made them distinct for each slideshow, I am going to change them to unique id's when I get a chance to finish them at home.  Do you think this could be the issue? @xianwill

Comment: yes it could be. since your javascript is setting the width of the list elements, you need to make sure your code is querying the elements correctly from the dom.